# echo stdin line by line into file

Tags: bash

I am trying to automate setting up Private Key Authentication for SSH.

Not sure how to achieve my desired result. I need to look stdin line by line into a file.

```
key(){
read -p "Paste Your Private Key Here: " privatekey

while read $privatekey; do
        echo $privatekey > ~/.ssh/id_rsa;
done


chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
chown work:work ~/.ssh/id_rsa
echo "Your SSH Key Authentication is setup!"
}
```

Can someone assist with this?

Thanks!

Comment: Remove the `$` in the `read` line: use `while read -r privatekey; do echo "$privatekey" >> ~/.ssh/id_rsa; done`.  Note that you do use double quotes around `"$privatekey"` as you echo it, and you don't want to zap the file each time round the loop, hence the `>>`.  You could also move the redirection outside the loop: while read -r privatekey; do echo "$privatekey"; done > ~/.ssh/id_rsa`.  And there are many equivalent questions.

Comment: Hello thanks for the help!

Comment: So two things. The first line of the input is not included in the output file which I would like it to be. And how would I make it so that it doesnt keep hanging waiting for more input. How would I make the loop end?

Comment: Don't do a `read` outside the loop; that'll get everything into the file.  Do indicate EOF when you're done: on Unix, type Control-D (usually; it is configurable).  Or define that the user can type a blank line, or 'exit' or 'done' or whatever and test for the condition when `read` returns and before the `echo`.  Use `break` to exit the loop.